# Using file paths in bash case statement

Tags: bash, case-statement

I'm trying to make the following script loop over the `part_arr` array elements and depending on the value the script should execute the commands. In this case I just used a `echo` statement. It doesn't seem to detect the paths. `part_arr` is the size and path of each partition starting with a `/` or `[`.

```
part_arr=$(lsblk -b | awk '/.*[\/\[].*/{ print $4, $7 }')

tmp=''

for i in "${part_arr[@]}"; do

    case "$i" in
    "/boot/efi" )
        echo $i     $tmp;;
    "/boot" )
        echo $i     $tmp;;
    "/var")
        echo $1     $tmp;;
    "/tmp")
        echo $1     $tmp;;
    "/home")
        echo $1     $tmp;;
    "[SWAP]")
        echo $1     $tmp;;
    "/")
        echo $1     $tmp;;
    esac

    tmp=i

done
```

Comment: `part_arr` isn't array, it's a single string. Are you missing `()` around your command substitution?

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminW. I needed a the following: `part_arr=($(lsblk -b | awk '/.*[\/\[].*/{ print $4, $7 }'))`. You can provide the solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach that does away with the case statement by using an array that can easily be edited. It might make maintenance slightly easier.

```
#!/bin/bash
part_arr=($(lsblk -b | awk '/.*[\/\[].*/{ print $4, $7 }'))
interesting=(
    '/'
    '/boot'
    '/boot/efi'
    '/etc/hosts'
    '/home'
    '/media/ebs0'
    '/tmp'
    '/var'
    '[SWAP]'
)
# Each entry is pair: (size, file-name).
for((i=0; i<${#part_arr[@]}; i+=2)) ; do
    fname=${part_arr[(($i+1))]}
    # O(log(N)) search is okay here because N is small.
    for j in ${interesting[@]} ; do
        if [[ "$j" == "$fname" ]] ; then
            fsize=${part_arr[$i]}
            printf '%-12s %s\n' $fname $fsize
            break
        fi
    done
done
```